# calling a super class in python is failing

Tags: python, super

```
class Pet:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        return None
    def show(self):
        print("Hi my self {} and am of {} old".format(self.name,self.age))
        return True
    def speak(self):
        print("I do speak but am a parent")
        return True

class Cat(Pet):
    def __initi__(self,name,age,breed):
        super.__init__(name,age)
        self.breed=breed
        return None
    def show(self):
        print("This is called from Child class Cat")
        return True
    def speak(self):
        print("This is Meaow")
        return True
    def reveal(self):
        print("this is {} and of {} and breed is {}".format(self.name,self.age,self.breed))
        return True
class Dog(Pet):
    def __init__(self,name,age,breed):
        super.__init__(name,age)
        self.breed=breed
        return None
    def show(self):
        print("This is called form Child class Dog")
        return True
    def speak(self):
        print("This is bow bow")
        return True
b=Cat("tim",2,"lago")
```

Comment: am getting Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/avinash/Desktop/Bills/Python/test49.py", line 38, in <module>
    b=Cat("tim",2,"lago")
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)

Comment: Why do you return None in the __init__??

Comment: Your question is mostly containing source code rather than information.. Add information rather than commenting `am getting Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/avinash/Desktop/Bills/Python/test49.py", line 38, in <module> b=Cat("tim",2,"lago") TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given) –`

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `super()` as a method, ie: add the two brackets.

If you just leave it like it is, you will get:

`TypeError: descriptor '__init__' requires a 'super' object but received a 'str'`

On top of that you had a typo, you had actually written `__initi__`.

This one below will work for you:

```py
class Pet:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        return None
    def show(self):
        print("Hi my self {} and am of {} old".format(self.name,self.age))
        return True
    def speak(self):
        print("I do speak but am a parent")
        return True

class Cat(Pet):
    def __init__(self,name,age,breed):
        super(Cat,self).__init__(name,age)
        self.breed=breed
        return None
    def show(self):
        print("This is called from Child class Cat")
        return True
    def speak(self):
        print("This is Meaow")
        return True
    def reveal(self):
        print("this is {} and of {} and breed is {}".format(self.name,self.age,self.breed))
        return True

class Dog(Pet):
    def __init__(self,name,age,breed):
        super(Dog,self).__init__(name,age)
        self.breed=breed
        return None
    def show(self):
        print("This is called form Child class Dog")
        return True
    def speak(self):
        print("This is bow bow")
        return True

b = Cat("tim",2,"lago")
```

Comment: raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/avinash/Desktop/Bills/Python/test55.py", line 40, in <module>
    b = Cat("tim",2,"lago")
  File "/Users/avinash/Desktop/Bills/Python/test55.py", line 15, in __init__
    super().__init__(name,age)
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
[Finished in 0.94s]

Comment: Which Python version are you using? I have edited my answer by modying the `super()` call. Does it work for you now?

Answer (score 1):

**Error # 1**
You have `__initi__` inside Cat class which should be `__init__`.

**Error # 2**
When calling `super` you must use parentheses `super()`.

Didn't get that why you use return None inside each class `__init__` method?

```
class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        return None

    def show(self):
        print("Hi my self {} and am of {} old".format(self.name, self.age))
        return True

    def speak(self):
        print("I do speak but am a parent")
        return True


class Cat(Pet):
    def __init__(self, name, age, breed):
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.breed = breed
        return None

    def show(self):
        print("This is called from Child class Cat")
        return True

    def speak(self):
        print("This is Meaow")
        return True

    def reveal(self):
        print("this is {} and of {} and breed is {}".format(self.name, self.age, self.breed))
        return True


class Dog(Pet):
    def __init__(self, name, age, breed):
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.breed = breed
        return None

    def show(self):
        print("This is called form Child class Dog")
        return True

    def speak(self):
        print("This is bow bow")
        return True


b = Cat("tim", 2, "lago")
```

Comment: raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/avinash/Desktop/Bills/Python/test55.py", line 40, in <module>
    b = Cat("tim",2,"lago")
  File "/Users/avinash/Desktop/Bills/Python/test55.py", line 15, in __init__
    super().__init__(name,age)
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
[Finished in 0.94s]